# Can't overlap #piano-keyboard-octave-black > button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a piano keyboard in HTML but I cannot get the black buttons to overlap white, even when using z-index: 1; in CSS. And I also want to get the keys to make a sound in JavaScript. And I also need to position the black key buttons so they're exactly between two white ones, and I can't get the white ones to be right next to each other, they are spacing out.

The code is

```js
// JavaScript coming soon.
```

```css
#piano-keyboard-octave-white > button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #ffffff);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: inherit;
  height: 156px;
}
#piano-keyboard-octave-white > button:active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cccccc, #eeeeee);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: inherit;
  height: 156px;
}
#piano-keyboard-octave-black > button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #111111, #000000);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: inherit;
  height: 62px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#piano-keyboard-octave-black {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="octaves-4">
                <!---->
                    <div id="piano-keyboard-octave-white">
                      <button>
                        C
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        D
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        E
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        F
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        G
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        A
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        B
                      </button>
                      <div id="piano-keyboard-octave-black">
                      <button>
                        C
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        D
                      </button>
                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;
                      <button>
                        E
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        F
                      </button>
                      <button>
                        G
                      </button>
                      
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <!---->
                    <piano-keyboard-octave emoji="" octave="4"></piano-keyboard-octave>
                <!---->
                    <piano-keyboard-octave emoji="" octave="5"></piano-keyboard-octave>
                <!---->
                    <piano-keyboard-octave emoji="" octave="6"></piano-keyboard-octave>
                <!---->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the keys `position:absolute;` for them to overlap like that. As for the spacing between elements, generally `flexbox` is used for cases like this.